# git command not working in visual studio event but in command line

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, cmd

I am trying to run `git log --pretty=format:"%ai %s%n" > "$(SolutionDir)\test.txt"` which only returns a lot of lines in the visual studio output like : `s\<PathToSolutionDir\test.txt`. Before that line I have another git command running perfectly and my first command is `cd /D <PathToProjectWithGit>`

Using the exact same command in cmd.exe works perfectly fine.

I already tried different methods of escaping \, %, ^, ", "", """, ...

Comment: Looks like you left out the close parenthesis after `SolutionDir`

Comment: ops sorry that is a typo... in the actual project there is the closing parenthesis

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? I've got the same problem here.

Comment: Nope never figured out why it was not working. See my self answer for a workaround. Worked for me and I am happy. I also never figured out why this question was down voted. If my self answer helps you vote it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik visual studio is calling cmd.exe in the background for the pre and post-build events... so for an workaround I used this at the start of my application:

```
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.CreateNoWindow = false;
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("cd /D C:\\your git repo on your local drive");
            sw.WriteLine("git log --pretty=format:"%ai %s" > "C:\\path to dir where log should be placed\\test.txt"
        }
    }
```

each sw.WriteLine(""); can be considered one line of command line input
essentially the same as pre or post build event...